# Sous-titres français vs version sonore français d'un film américain

Tags: cinéma

Actuellement, je regarde la version française des films hollywoodiens accompagnée par ses sous-titres.

Ce que j'ai observé c'est que, si on compare la version originale et ses sous-titres anglais (américains) la correspondance est presque biunivoque. Les sous-titres suivent les dialogues sans différences majeures.

Or, cela n'est pas le cas pour la VF et ses sous-titres. Pourquoi alors les sous-titres français sont-ils souvent si différents des dialogues de la version sonore française ?

Comment: Le terme « biunivoque »  ressort strictement du domaine mathématique; croyez-vous qu'il soit utilisable sans une sorte d'avertissement au lecteur ? Il implique une complexité plutôt très technique qui dépasse le lecteur normal: les termes choisis dans une langue n'ont qu'une seule interprétation dans l'autre; qu'est-ce qui est dit vraiment ?  Est-ce qu'il n'y a pas de double entendre ([Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre)) ?

Comment: et ne te laisse pas impressionner. *Biunivoque* est très bien ! ;-)

Comment: @LPH *Double entendre*, en dépit des apparences, est depuis longtemps une expression exclusivement anglaise.